# Is there an equivalent windows command for chmod?

Tags: php, windows, apache, chmod, chgrp

I'm currently setting up a PHP app to run on my local machine (windows). The README describes the steps to run to set up the app on the production sever (linux).

I've come accross these steps:

```
mkdir var/cache/
chgrp apache -R var/cache/
chmod 770 -R var/cache/
```

and

```
cd public/
chgrp apache -R photos/
chmod 770 -R photos/
```

How would I go about performing these commands on a windows machine (from cmd or powershell)?

I'm using PHP/Apache via XAMPP.

Comment: I use the terminal [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Lets you use Linux commands in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses NTFS filesystem which doesn't have permissions applied in the same way as chmod (ext4) works. There are lots of features missing and features that just work differently.

I'm pretty sure that as long as you're using the same user on your PC, you don't have to be bothered by this. You can probably skip applying chmod commands.

However, i highly recommend you to check out [`Windows Subsystem for Linux 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

It is a way to run Linux inside your Windows PC without running a chunky virtual machine (it's very *lightweight* and *fast*). Developing PHP with Linux filesystem and kernel is a *way better* experience. The technology is very mature by now and can even run Docker.